# Unable to connect SharePoint search to an external Jive webite

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, search, search-results

I am working on Search in SharePoint 2016 OnPrem. The content source is an external website. I 'can' connect to external sites but having difficulties connecting to this one external site built on the Jive technology.

My Content Source for SharePoint to connect to an external Jive website looks like this:

[image]

and after running a full crawl to get content from external Jive website, this is what I see in the crawl warning message:

[image]

I'm not quite sure what this opensearch.xml url is all about.

Has someone been able to crawl an external Jive site from SharePoint before?

I even created a Crawl Rule to crawl the external Jive site, the Crawl Rule looks like this:

[image]

Is there anything I'm missing here when creating a Crawl Rule or the Content source?

Perhaps I need to do something on the Jive site itself to allow SharePoint to crawl its data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As your crawl rule is using Anonymous access, you need to make sure the external site has enabled anonymous access. Otherwise, you need to use an account in your crawl rule and the account should have at least Read permission on the external site.

Answer (score 0):

In your Crawl rules options ,

you have selected Include all items in the path, but did not select any sub options.

Try selecting with "Crawl Complex Rules"(second sub option.)

[image: Highlighted the selection]

Also check your robot.txt file in the website whether that site is allowed  to crawl by any search crawl engines.

The next point is Access, ensure that anonymous access is enabled.